# Making a memoryview C-contiguous Fortran-contiguous

Tags: python, fortran, cython, contiguous

I am using C-contiguous memoryviews in my Python code and I would like to use `dgemm` which needs Fortran-contiguous memoryviews.
I would like to use the function **PyMemoryView_GetContiguous** found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/buffer.html) but I don't know how to access it.

Does someone know which import I have to do ?

I don't want to use the function copy_fortran() as it really slows down my code.

Comment: A comment as this is a bit of a guess: It looks as though you currently have the matrices stored in row major order, which is the transpose of what you think you want. But can you use C(T)=(AB)(T)=B(T)A(T) with the transpose options in dgemm to avoid having to change the memory layout?  (Where (T) means take the transpose)

Comment: This is finally how I solved my problem. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PyMemoryView_GetContiguous` doesn't look to be exposed as part of the Cython standard includes unfortunately. It should be reasonably easy to wrap though:

```
from cpython.buffer cimport PyBUF_READ # we'll need this later

cdef extern from "Python.h":
    # copy the signature replacing PyObject* with object to let Cython
    # handle the reference counting
    object PyMemoryView_GetContiguous(object, int, char)

def test(double[:,::1] c_contig):
   f_contig = PyMemoryView_GetContiguous(c_contig, PyBuf_READ,'F')
   # .... do something useful
```

Be aware that this will still involve copying all the memory (this is absolutely unavoidable!) so is unlikely to be significantly faster than `copy_fortran`.

---

There's a problem though - `PyMemoryView_GetContiguous` won't return a writeable memoryview unless it does not have to make a copy, and Cython requires things assigned to a typed memoryview be writeable, so you can only use it as a Python object.

You can get a pointer to the first element though - the underlying object that created is a `bytes`/`str` object, so you can get a `char*` then cast that to whatever pointer you need. This should be enough to call your Fortran functions:

```
cdef char* as_bytes = f_contig.obj
some_function(<double*>as_bytes)
```